# SASS// Background Image path issue

Tags: css, sass, background-image

I'm trying to set a background image for a class.

This is my file structure using laravel-mix:

[image]

What's wrong with my code in app.scss file?

```
.header-bg {
   background-image: url('img/illustration-main.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Tried this but also not working:

```
.header-bg {
   background-image: url(require('img/illustration-main.jpg'));
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Here in case the content of the img folder:

[image]

Comment: your url path is relative from your css file... so it's looking under `src/img/....` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your css file is being built to `dist/app.css` your image path should be relative to this. Since your `img` folder is sibling to `dist`, try `url('../img/illustration-main.jpg')`

Comment: Thank you, but i really don't understand why, it's not working ;(